# Angular CLI 1.4.1 , ng always generate spec file and css even default prefix is scss

Tags: node.js, angular, angular-cli, angular-components

I recently updated my Angular CLI version to 1.4.1, After updation I created new

project using following command

```
 F:\Projects\MyCLIProject>ng new FlexCSS --prefix=cf --skip-install --skip-git  --style=scss --skip-tests
```

*And when I ran below command to create new component, What I saw is it still generating spec file as well as style file extension is also  CSS.*

Please see below output

```
F:\Projects\MyCLIProject>ng g c textComp
  create src/app/text-comp/text-comp.component.html (28 bytes)
  create src/app/text-comp/text-comp.component.spec.ts (643 bytes)
  create src/app/text-comp/text-comp.component.ts (280 bytes)
  create src/app/text-comp/text-comp.component.css (0 bytes)
  update src/app/app.module.ts (406 bytes)
```

*I don't know whether its happening only with me , or someone else also facing same problem.*

I created projects many times as well as re-installed angular cli without clearing npm cache.

Here is my **.angular-cli.json**

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "project": {
    "name": "MyCLIProject"
  },
  "apps": [
    {
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "dist",
      "assets": [
        "assets",
        "favicon.ico"
      ],
      "index": "index.html",
      "main": "main.ts",
      "polyfills": "polyfills.ts",
      "test": "test.ts",
      "tsconfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
      "testTsconfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
      "prefix": "cf",
      "styles": [
        "styles.scss"
      ],
      "scripts": [],
      "environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
      "environments": {
        "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
        "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
      }
    }
  ],
  "e2e": {
    "protractor": {
      "config": "./protractor.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "lint": [
    {
      "project": "src/tsconfig.app.json"
    },
    {
      "project": "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
    },
    {
      "project": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json"
    }
  ],
  "test": {
    "karma": {
      "config": "./karma.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "defaults": {
    "styleExt": "scss",
    "component": {
      "spec":false
     }
  }
}
```

Here is my ng version

```
F:\Projects\MyCLIProject>ng version
    _                      _                 ____ _     ___
   / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
  / △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | |
 / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | |
/_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
               |___/
@angular/cli: 1.4.1
node: 8.4.0
os: win32 x64
@angular/animations: 4.3.6
@angular/common: 4.3.6
@angular/compiler: 4.3.6
@angular/core: 4.3.6
@angular/forms: 4.3.6
@angular/http: 4.3.6
@angular/platform-browser: 4.3.6
@angular/platform-browser-dynamic: 4.3.6
@angular/router: 4.3.6
@angular/cli: 1.4.1
@angular/compiler-cli: 4.3.6
@angular/language-service: 4.3.6
typescript: 2.3.4

F:\Projects\MyCLIProject>npm --version
5.3.0
```

Comment: This is an open issue: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/7644. SO cannot help you further with this.

Comment: Thanks jonrsharpe...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [@angular/cli: 1.4.1 Angular Generate Component but it returns home.component.css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46172103/angular-cli-1-4-1-angular-generate-component-but-it-returns-home-component-css)

Comment: @Nico Van Belle , How can be this question duplicate , If it is raised earlier than mentioned one.

Comment: @Viraj Nothing personal, don't feel bad. I only mark this question as duplicate as the other topic has answers so when somebody sees this topic he can navigate to the other topic