# @angular/cli: 1.4.1 Angular Generate Component but it returns home.component.css

Tags: node.js, angular, angular-cli, angular-components

```
$npm install -g @angular/cli
$ng new angular --routing --style=sass
$ng g c home
 "apps": [
    {
      "styles": [
           "styles.sass"
      ],
    }

"defaults": {
    "styleExt": "sass",
    "component": {
    }
  }
```

I want to sass style in angular, I use angular cli, I try to generate component it returns with style with prefix css. May you help me to fixing that? Thanks in advance for your answer.

Comment: How do you generate your component?

Comment: @jhen it is in the question: `ng g c home`

Comment: I use this **ng g c home**

Comment: before I use @angular/cli: 1.3.2 it's working but @angular/cli: 1.4.1 it isn't working.

Comment: I downgraded Angular CLI to 1.3.2 until they resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just migrated from `@angular/cli@1.0.3` to `@angular/cli@1.4.2` and I am facing the same issue. Turns out it's due to a bug introduced in v1.4.1 so we can only wait for a new angular-cli release that will fix this bug.
In v1.4.1 also the `apps.prefix` is ignored but this was fixed in v1.4.2.

In the mean time, the workaround provided by @Derlin can be used.

github issues on this topic:

- https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/7624
- https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/7682
- https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/7644
- https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/7647
- https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/7522

**update:**

The issue is fixed in `@angular/cli@1.4.3`. Check [this release note](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/releases/tag/v1.4.3).

> @angular/cli: Generating component considers default style extension
>   for project now

Answer (score 2):

To override the default style, you can use the option `--style [css|scss|sass]`:

```
ng g c home --style=css
```

Comment: You shouldn't have to append `--style` every time if you have defined `styleExt` as you did. This answer might be good as a temporary workaround, but you shouldn't have to do it like this really.

Comment: Temporary this is fine, until bug is fixed

Answer (score 1):

Here is my defaults that works :

```
"defaults": {
  "styleExt": "scss",
  "prefixInterfaces": false,
  "inline": {
    "style": false,
    "template": false
  },
  "spec": {
    "class": false,
    "component": true,
    "directive": true,
    "module": false,
    "pipe": true,
    "service": true
  }
}
```

Otherwise, you can just rename it.